# Are wallpaper apps considered repetitive content?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, google-play, android-wallpaper

I have lots of content to create wallpaper apps from.

However, I have known google to be heavy on banning recently. I am concerned that the Google play policy of "Do not post repetitive content" will get me banned.

Some developers have lots of wallpaper apps of different subjects like I will.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Artem+Chop

Same UI throughout. This is also my intention.

How best to proceed? Any experience with this? Wish I could get "permission" from Google Play!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play policies and their enforcement. Answers would be heavily anecdotal at best. There's no way SO community could give a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks - Where best to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Artem Chop account is removed from Google Play

http://www.appannie.com/apps/google-play/publisher/20200000435256/?&page=last